# I installed XAMP on Mac: I found htdocs, where do I find the folders in my localhost web browser?

Tags: mysql, macos, apache, xampp

I opened the localhost:8080/phpmyadmin in my browser and created a new database. Then I located the XAMP app from my mac application folder to find "htdocs". Inside I found the other "my.cnf" "php.ini" "proftpd.conf" and "httpd.conf" files. I opened each one of them to find my new database folder or the other default folders and none of it is their.

The other Youtube videos show it is located just under the htdocs folder, but none of the databases are their. How do I locate my database?

Also if someone can answer this, can I move that folder into my desktop and work from their?

Comment: Your database would not be in the web document folder. That's a bad idea, security-wise. I'd recommend leaving the database files where they are, so mysql can find them. You never want to modify the database files directly.

Comment: Thanks! I did find it under the "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql". However, the database I created and the other default files that was already there; are showing "you don't have permission to view the content". I'm the single user on my mac. I looked through the localhost:8080/phpmyadmin to find and edit the permissions but can't find it. Where do I change the settings to allow me to upload my codes?

Comment: Use the MySQL command line client, phpmyadmin, or another program to modify your databases. Do **not** edit the files directly.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* theoretically move the folder to your desktop. It is not recommended to do so, as the desktop is where you most likely have all your important files, if you are a typical user. The database should be stored in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
I believe that you are using macOS, as described by the title, and as such, that is where XAMPP should be storing your database files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MAMP . I think its better to use MAMP for MAC rather xampp. 
https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/

If you are still using xampp. 
Try to find your databases under
xampp\mysql\data ..

Thanks.